# Uncaught ReferenceError: "changing" is not defined (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, function, reference

I am trying to make a function which is call when a

"Try it" button 
is clicked and a loop run inside the function where a word is change using loop

I am new to JavaScript but old to programming.

It's kind of confusing if compared with C or C++

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        #demo {
            font-size: 600%;
            color: red;
        }

    </style>
    <script>
        function changing() {
            var my = undefined;
            for (count = 1; count < 3; count++) {
                if (count == 1) {
                    my = LIFE;
                    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = my;
                } else if (count == 2) {
                    my = STYLE;
                    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = my;
                } else if (count == 3) {
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>My First Web Page</h1>
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    <div id="demo">AWESOME</div>

    <button type="button" onclick="changing()">Try it</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error parts :

```
else if (count == 3) {
{
```

You opened 2 curly braces

also use `"LIFE"` instead of `LIFE` and `"STYLE"~ instead of`STYLE`

```js
function changing() {
            var my = undefined;
            for (count = 1; count < 3; count++) {
                if (count == 1) {
                    my = "LIFE";
                    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = my;
                } else if (count == 2) {
                    my = "STYLE";
                    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = my;
                } else if (count == 3) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        #demo {
            font-size: 600%;
            color: red;
        }

    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <h1>My First Web Page</h1>
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    <div id="demo">AWESOME</div>

    <button type="button" onclick="changing()">Try it</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember about quotation marks when using `strings`. Else, it will be treated as a `variable`. And since it hasn't been declared - function will throw errors.

```js
function changing() {
  var my;
  for (count = 1; count < 3; count++) {
    if (count == 1) {
      my = 'LIFE';
      document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = my;
    } else if (count == 2) {
      my = 'STYLE';
      document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = my;
    } else if (count == 3) {
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#demo {
  font-size: 600%;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>My First Web Page</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
<div id="demo">AWESOME</div>

<button type="button" onclick="changing()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: I deleted the comment. In your program, its ok. But OP missed one closing braces. You can check it. He closed till for loop

Comment: @SagarV Whatever. Anyways I just wonder why your answer got 2 upvotes immediately after you posted it. Even if you were one minute late after me :)

Comment: anyway, you are at 4.7K and me at only 1.6K. :-( upvoted.